# Multiple Class name and apply CSS depending on class name combinations

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I am finding hard to understand on how to apply multiple CSS depending on the Class name combination.

I have a two div tags this way

```
<div class="on appr">
  <div class"sc"> Text1 </div></div>

<div class="ne appr">
  <div class"sc"> Text1 </div></div>
```

Now i wanted to apply two different styles depending on the class name combination
For example when class name is **on** and **app** then i want background color be red.
When class name is **ne** and **app** then i want background color be Green...etc

I tried this:

```
.on.appr{background-color: #7FFFE7;} 
.ne.appr{background-color: #49EEAA;}
```

but it was not working it is just applying one color.

Any help on to define this please? A solution using Jquery is also fine for me. Thank you!

**Updating with Complete Code**

May it is worth mentioning since i am doing it correct in my CSS declaration.
I am using FullCalendar and I am passing a className to the fullCalendar Event. when I use firebug, i see that the className i pass to the calendar events.

Below is what i see in Firebug for the calendar entry.

```
<div class="fc-event fc-event-skin fc-event-hori on appr"
     style="position: absolute;    z-index: 8; left: 0px; width: 1100px; top: 307px;">
    <div class="fc-event-inner fc-event-skin">
    <span class="fc-event-title">(on)Jeff</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Below is the code i have it in my .jsp file.

```
 <style type="text/css">

.pen .fc-event-skin
    {
border-color:red;
color:red;
font-weight: bold; 
font-size: 10pt;
background-color: yellow;
    }


.on.appr.fc-event-skin
{
background-color: green;
font-weight: bold; 
font-size: 10pt;
}

   .ne.appr.fc-event-skin
{
background-color: red;
color:yellow;
font-weight: bold; 
font-size: 10pt;

}

</style>
```

Comment: app or appr ??...in our question class name is `app` & in code `appr`

Answer (score 2):

```
.on.appr{background-color: #7FFFE7;}
```

change this

```
.ne.appr{background-color: 49EEAA;}
```

to

```
.ne.appr{background-color: #49EEAA;}
```

You're missing a "#" on the second CSS declaration. Try adding that to the color. If that doesn't work then you're overriding it somehow further down your css file.

Comment: You're code works. You are overwriting it somewhere else in your css file. Proof here: http://jsfiddle.net/FMuh9/ ... you might also want to add display:block; to your divs if you aren't.

Comment: okay...in fact i have the above styles in the <head> and rest of ANY other styles i have in linked file..Still not sure why only the last color was applying.

Comment: Hi Stone, i update my code i have above...Please validate it. Thanks!

Comment: The HTML you've posted is for a div inside another div. Both divs are the same size and thus the front-most div will cover the bottom one - so you're only seeing one color. You can see what I mean if you resize one of them (and remove the unnecessary .pen as it's not used in the HTML you've posted). proof: http://jsfiddle.net/C5jFY/

Comment: But .pen i might have some data with pen as class name so i had. However what i see is i always see red even for 'on appr'...which is the last style in my code. For the ones that i have class as 'pen'- Style is applying fine...(no issues with it)...Only problem is when i get 'on app' and 'ne appr' as class name...for all of these only Red is getting applied as the background-color. When i try the same in jsfiddle link you pasted it is working fine...dont know if this is something to do with FullCalendar plug-in

Comment: I understand, but for the code you've posted above - my answer is correct. the class .pen isn't in your example code. You'll have to post all of your code on the page for me to help further. jsfiddle.net would be most helpful in doing so.